# Hibernate Annotations: Class extends Vector<>

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations

Hibernate wont insert the Vector's data in the db.
How can I instruct hibernate to do this?

What I want is a table "tbl_right" with a foreign key "id_licence" which refers to the licence.

I was searching and trying more than one day for a solution, but I couldn't find something.
Seems like no one else has a similar problem.

Has someone an idea how to solve it?

That is the class I'm talking about:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tbl_licence")
public class Licence extends Vector<Right> implements ILicence {

    public Licence(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
    private int db_id;
    private String description = "No description for Licence";  
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    public int getDb_id() {
        return db_id;
    }
    public void setDb_id(int db_id) {
        this.db_id = db_id;

    }    
    @Column(name = "DESCRIPTION")
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }   
    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }   
}
```

Possible Solution:

```
@OneToMany(targetEntity = Right.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "ID_LICENCE")
public Collection<Right> getCollection() {
    Collection<Right> c = new Vector<>();
    for(Right r : this){
        c.add(r);
    }
    return c;
}

public void setCollection(Collection<Right> rights) {
    this.clear();
    this.addAll(rights);
}
```

Comment: This design makes me cry. Why is your `Licence` class extending from `Vector`? What's your real problem?

Comment: Hi, because a Licence is a Vector<Right>. That's the idea.
But Hibernate doesn't save the Vector elements.

Comment: Why do you think a `Licence` is a `Vector` to begin with?